# add class to first 5 element from every 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
<div class="cube"></div>
<div class="cube"></div>
<div class="cube"></div>
<div class="cube"></div>
<div class="cube"></div>
<div class="cube"></div>
```

add class to first 5 element from every 10. have many Divs

Comment: So it should repeat for every group of 10? Are they all siblings? Can you just use CSS selectors, or do you really need the class on the elements?

Comment: You can do it using `javascript`...what have you tried?

Comment: You want to add extra class itself or just style them?

Comment: @ErekleChumburidze _"have many Divs"_ Can include full `html` at Question ? Do `.cube` elements have parent element other than `body` ? What `class` should be added to first five elements ?

Comment: This Cubes are appended in row have 96 cubes and have 36 rows. I need add class DISABLED based on Time. so I need add class with javascript.

Comment: @ErekleChumburidze  _"Cubes are appended in row have 96 cubes and have 36 rows."_ `.cube` elements have a parent element ? , a `td` or `tr` element ? Can include `html` example of a "row" at Question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
var counter = 0;
$('.cube').each(function(i) {
   if (i % 10 == 0) {
       counter = 1;
   } else {
       counter++;
   }
   if (counter < 5) {
       $(this).addClass('something');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a pretty nice approach using jQuery

```
// Loops through each cube element
$('.cube').each(function(index) {
  // Gets the last integer in the index (ie. 0-9)
  var num = (index + 1) % 10;
  // If 1,2,3,4 or 5
  if (num <= 5 && num > 0)
    // Add the new class
    $(this).addClass('newClass');
});
```

Here is a full example

```js
$('.cube').each(function(index) {
  var num = (index + 1) % 10;
  if (num <= 5 && num > 0)
    $(this).text('new cube');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cube">cube</div>
<div class="cube">cube</div>
<div class="cube">cube</div>
<div class="cube">cube</div>
<div class="cube">cube</div>
<div class="cube">cube</div>
<div class="cube">cube</div>
<div class="cube">cube</div>
<div class="cube">cube</div>
<div class="cube">cube</div>
```

Comment: Actually on second thought, it will.  I guess I shouldn't trust my math skills.  :/

Answer (score 2):

This is CSS approach using [`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child)  pseudo-class

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: decimal;  
}

li:nth-child(10n+1),
li:nth-child(10n+2),
li:nth-child(10n+3),
li:nth-child(10n+4),
li:nth-child(10n+5){
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$().ready(function(){
    var counter = 0;
    $(".cube").each(function(idx,obj)
    {
        counter++;
        if(counter <= 5 )
        {

            $(obj).addClass('newstyle');
        }
        if(counter == 10) counter = 0;


    })
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just determine what the last digit is, and if less than 5, add class.  Could be one line in the function but I assigned a variable for readability.

```
$('div').each(function(i){
     var num = parseInt(i.slice(-1));
     $(this).toggleClass('cube', num < 5);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Using javascript, use a two counter, one for every 10 divs and another for the first 5 divs and with `jquery addClass`, it is easy.